# Scala, Extend object with a generic trait

Tags: scala, singleton, extend, type-mismatch, traits

I'm using Scala and I want to extend a (singleton) object with a trait, which delivers a data structure and some methods, like this:

```
trait Tray[T] {
  val tray = ListBuffer.empty[T]

  def add[T] (t: T) = tray += t
  def get[T]: List[T] = tray.toList
}
```

And then I'll would like to mix-in the trait into an object, like this:

```
object Test with Tray[Int]
```

But there are type mismatches in `add` and `get`:

```
Test.add(1)
// ...
```

How can I'll get this to work? Or what is my mistake?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that you're shadowing the trait's type parameter with the `T` on the `add` and `get` methods. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13830404/334519) for more detail about the problem.

Here's the correct code:

```
trait Tray[T] {
  val tray = ListBuffer.empty[T]

  def add (t: T) = tray += t      // add[T] --> add
  def get: List[T] = tray.toList  // get[T] --> add
}

object Test extends Tray[Int]
```

Note the use of `extends` in the object definition—see section 5.4 of [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for an explanation of why `with` alone doesn't work here.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll think it's because scala disassemble internal all objects to functions, and this causes this shadowing problem!

Comment: @Themerius: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean, but the problem's actually pretty simple—you can introduce a new type name in a method's type parameter list that's spelled the same as an existing type name outside of the method. You can do exactly the same thing in Java.

Comment: Sure, it's a scope thing. Therefore it's more a feature. :)