# Found scala.Unit, required Unit

Tags: scala, types

I have a simple container trait like so:

```
trait Handler {
  def apply[In, Out](in: In): Out
}
```

When I try to implement it:

```
new Handler {
  def apply[Any, Unit](in: Any) = println(in)
}
```

I get an error:

```
[error]  found   : scala.Unit
[error]  required: Unit(in method apply)
[error]       def apply[Any, Unit](in: Any) = println(in)
```

Why is this? Can I fix this compiler error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala type parameter error, not a member of type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489716/scala-type-parameter-error-not-a-member-of-type-parameter)

Comment: It does sound similar, but I'm not sure how I would resolve my issue. To be honest, `Handler` was a trait, not a class, so I'm not overriding anything, just implementing `apply`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is almost the same question with correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14023882/406435).

You could use trait type parameter, not method type parameter:

```
trait Handler[Out] {
  def apply[In](in: In): Out
}

new Handler[Unit] {
  def apply[In](in: In) = println(in)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. I had tried having both `In` and `Out` being trait type parameters, but that just got crazy complicated. This works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't create a class with abstract (not implemented) method, you should either change `class` to `trait` or add `abstract` before the `class` keyword.

When you r implementing apply method, `Unit` is a type variable for this method and scala inferring the type of your method as scala.Unit because it is the result type of the `Predef.println` method

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific: it's actually a trait. As for your second point, how do I avoid using the `Unit` type variable and actually use `scala.Unit`?

Answer (score 0):

what about this solution ?

```
trait Handler {
  type In
  type Out

  def apply(in: In): Out
}

new Handler {
  type In=Any
  type Out=Unit

  override def apply(in: In):Out = println(in)
}
```

Comment: The problem, it seems, is that the output type is type `Handler.Out`, not the actual output type used.

Comment: yes but it is a Unit you can assign it without any problems : val h : Unit = res0("what ever") (given res0 is the result of the Handler creation)