# Scala type parameter error, not a member of type parameter

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement a generic Adapter for Android in Scala. These are my classes:

```
class ScalaAdapter[A <: AnyRef](context: Context, resource: Int, objectsList: ArrayBuffer[A], adapterCb: AfAdapterItemCb) extends BaseAdapter with Filterable {...}
```

And the trait which every user of Adapter has to implement is:

```
trait AfAdapterItemCb {
  def itemCb[A](item: A, view: View) {}
}
```

My model class is:

```
case class ScheduleItem(name: String, priority: Int)
```

When I am implementing the Callback trait, I am getting an error related to type parameter:

```
  private class AdapterCbImpl extends AfAdapterItemCb {
    override def itemCb[ScheduleItem](schedule: ScheduleItem, view: View) = {      
      view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name).asInstanceOf[TextView].setText(schedule.name)
      view.findViewById(R.id.tv_priority).asInstanceOf[TextView].setText(schedule.priority.toString)
    }
  }
```

When I try to use a schedule object to fill the view, I am getting an error:

```
value name is not a member of type parameter ScheduleItem
value priority is not a member of type parameter ScheduleItem
```

I could not understand Manifest to fix it. Does someone understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) noted, this is called *shadowing*, and can be [extremely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023712/scala-extend-object-with-a-generic-trait/14023882#14023882) [annoying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830279/generic-type-inference-in-scala/13830404#13830404).

```
override def itemCb[ScheduleItem](schedule: ScheduleItem, view: View) = {
```

`ScheduleItem` here is a type parameter name, just like `T`. It have nothing with `case class ScheduleItem`.

You can't override method with type parameter using concrete type.

I don't know how to use `AfAdapterItemCb`, but you could try something like this:

```
override def itemCb[T](item: T, view: View) = item match {
  case schedule: ScheduleItem => ... //your code
  case _ => ... // item is not a ScheduleItem
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is called _shadowing_, and can be [extremely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14023882/334519) [annoying](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13830404/334519).

Comment: @TravisBrown: I forgot to look for existing answers, my fault.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working now. So is that whenever we use generic types(T) we have to use match-case? We can't use a specified type in place of T?

Comment: @Srinivas: `AdapterCbImpl extends AfAdapterItemCb` [means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) that an instance of `AdapterCbImpl` is an instance of `AfAdapterItemCb`, so method `itemCb[T]` could be called with any type parameter. You can't add restrictions with `override`.

Comment: @senia: If I don't mention override keyword, I am getting an error  _overriding method itemCb in trait AfAdapterItemCb of type [A](item: A, view: android.view.View)Unit;  method itemCb needs `override'_

Comment: @Srinivas You can use a specified type instead of T.  You just have to add the type parameter to the trait and not to the method.