# Method with type parameter does not compile

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, type-parameter

Now I'm not pretending that this code is good programming practice, but I don't understand why it won't compile. What's going on here?

```
object CustomTo extends App {
  val thing:Something = new Something
  val str:String = thing.to[String]
  println(str)
}

class Something {
  def to[String]:String = {
    "hello"
  }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
CustomTo.scala:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("hello")
 required: String
    "hello"
    ^
one error found
```

Comment: it's actually a very bad practice what you are doing here... You named your type parameter a `String`. just replace it with something like `T` and you will understand why it does not compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala type parameter error, not a member of type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489716/scala-type-parameter-error-not-a-member-of-type-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your type parameter `String` instead of `T`, but that doesn't make it less abstract, it can still be anything.

```
def to[String]:String 
// is the same as
def to[T]:T
```

If you want to create a generic `.to[T]` function that returns hello when called with `String`, i.e. you want to pattern match on a type, you can use a  `TypeTag`:

*Edit*: I just overlooked that the return type needs to be `T`, which means a useless cast has to be there, see below.

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

def to[T : TypeTag] = (typeOf[T] match {
  case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => "hello"
  case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => 1
  case _ => ???
}).asInstanceOf[T]
```

and:

```
scala> to[String]
res13: String = hello

scala> to[Int]
res14: Int = 1

scala> to[Double]
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
...
```

I am not sure there is a way to have the compiler infer on its own that things inside the pattern match have the correct types. It may be possible with `ClassTag`, but you would lose type safety with `.to[List[Int]]` and similar...

Comment: Accepted for reading my mind. Is there a way I can narrow the return type? `val str:String = thing.to[String].asInstanceOf[String]` Is it possible to return the requested type by default?

Comment: @tsjnsn good point, the return type isn't very nice. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler expects "String", if you would have put

```
class Something {
  def to[T]:T = {
    "hello"
  }
}
```

You would get something like `"required: T"`. In other words, you bind "String" to some type. There is not a lot of sense making in your example right now. What are you trying to  accomplish?

Comment: I wanted to be able to say something like `thing.to[String]` or `thing.to[Int]` , so a definition like this: (even though types cant be compared like I'm showing)
`def to[A]:A = {
  if (A == String) => "hello";
  if (A == Int) => 0;
}`