# Type mismatch found when implementing traits with parameter in the return

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, type-mismatch, traits

I have a trait as follows:

```
trait SomeBaseTrait{
  def someFun[B](args:SomeArgs)(f: => B):B
}
```

In my test class, I am trying to mock this class as follows:

```
class MyMockOfBase extends SomeBaseTrait{
     def someFun[Boolean](args:SomeArgs)(f: => Boolean):Boolean = true
}
```

The problem here is that compiling this class throws the following:

```
[error]  found   : scala.Boolean(true)
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]   def someFun[Boolean](args:SomeArgs)(f: => Boolean):Boolean = true
[error]                                                                ^
[error] one error found
```

Edit.

Also, Things are also a little weird when my trait has a method as follows:

```
 trait SomeBaseTrait2{
    def someFun2[B](args:SomeArgs):B
  }
```

I am extending it as follows:

```
val mockBase = new SomeBaseTrait2{def someFun2(args:SomeArgs):Boolean = true}
```

Now here I get the following:

```
new SomeBaseTrait2{def someFun2(args:String):Boolean = true}
<console>:9: error: object creation impossible, since method someFun2 in trait SomeBaseTrait2 of type [B](args: String)B is not defined
              new SomeBaseTrait2{def someFun2(args:String):Boolean = true}
```

Can somebody tell me what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala type parameter error, not a member of type parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489716/scala-type-parameter-error-not-a-member-of-type-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `MyMockOfBase` `Boolean` is the name of type parameter, just like `T`:

```
class MyMockOfBase extends SomeBaseTrait{
     def someFun[T](args:SomeArgs)(f: => T):T= true
}
```

You are trying to use `true` as `T`.

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
trait SomeBaseTrait[B]{
  def someFun(args:SomeArgs)(f: => B):B
}

class MyMockOfBase extends SomeBaseTrait[Boolean]{
     def someFun(args:SomeArgs)(f: => Boolean):Boolean = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I reread my question I realized it was incomplete,as you pointed out shadowing was the reason for this particular error but things were a little wonky when I had method in my trait like def someFun2[B](args:SomeArgs):B. My edit will elaborate on what I observed.

Comment: @sc_ray: It's all the same. There should be a type parameter in the method `someFun2` of `SomeBaseTrait2`. You can specify concrete type instead of type parameter with inheritance only for type parameters of trait or class, not for type parameters of method. You can specify type parameter of method only when you call it. You should just use `trait SomeBaseTrait[B]` from my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I don't want to tie my base trait to a particular type?

Comment: @sc_ray: what do you mean? Add use-case please. If method of the base type can return different types then method of the subclass should behave the same way. You can't remove type parameter from the method just because of the [substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).