# Generic Programming in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, generic-programming

Hi all I am fairly new to Scala coming from C#.

I am attempting to write my own version of accumulate ( fold) I am wondering why I am running into some issues with the following:

```
def accumulate[T](list : List[T], initial: T, f: (T, T) => T) : T = {
    @tailrec def loop[T](list: List[T], accum: T) : T =
      if(list.length == 0)
        accum
      else{
        val head : T = list.head
        val res : T = f(accum,head)
        loop[T](list.tail, res)
      }
    loop(list,initial)
  }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : accum.type (with underlying type T)
 required: T
        val res : T = f(accum,head)
                        ^
```

I cant see how I have a type mismatch considering everything is type T.

Any thoughts / help would be appreciated.

Blair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just remove type parameter from `loop` method. Replace `loop[T]` with `loop`.

With `loop[T]` you are creating new type parameter with name `T`, so `T` outside `loop` method and `T` in `loop` method are different type aliases with the same name.

It's called **shadowing**.

See these answers for similar problems:

1. [Scala type parameter error, not a member of type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16489817/406435)
2. [Scala, Extend object with a generic trait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14023882/406435)
3. [Generic type inference in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13830404/406435)

Comment: Ahh so obvious now :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that with the inner function `loop` you are defining a new type `T` that is shadowing the outer type `T`.

The compiler sees them as defining different types. If you simply remove the `T` type parameter from `loop` (including the recursive call `loop(list.tail, res)`) you should find it compiles just fine.