# Scala type bounds

Tags: scala

What is wrong with the code below?  I'm getting the following complaint from the compiler on the indicated line: type arguments [Asset] do not conform to trait Worker's type parameter bounds [T <: 
 br.Doable]

How is this so?  Worker expects a subtype of Doable, and asset extends Doable.

```
trait Doable

trait Worker[T<:Doable] {
  def hey():String
}

case class Asset() extends Doable

case class Hey[Asset] extends Worker[Asset] { // << error here
  def hey() = "You!"
}
```

Comment: Type parameter in the case class declaration messes things up, `case class Hey() extends Worker[Asset] { def hey() = "You!" }` works just fine. As to *why*, no idea, although I haven't really put much thought to it, honestly :)

Comment: `case class Hey[Asset] extends Worker[Asset]` and `case class Hey[T] extends Worker[T]` means the same. `Asset` here is just a new name for type parameter of class `Hey`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19137992/406435

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare `case class Hey[Asset]`, you bind a new type variable `Asset`, you do not refer to `case class Asset() extends Doable` (you are shadowing the `Asset` type variable).
Your code is equivalent to :

```
  case class Hey[A] extends Worker[A] {
    ...
  }
```

which obviously won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have confused yourself by using the same value, `Asset`, to refer to a case class and a type parameter.

You probably intend to do something like this:

```
case class Hey[T](str: String) extends Worker[Asset] { 
  def hey() = "You!"
}
```

Though it is beside the point, note that I added a parameter to `Hey` because case classes without parameters have been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a lot of times, and I think that the confusion can easily go away if you see the analogy between type parameters and constructor parameters, thinking about them just as different kinds of constructor parameters: type-level and value-level.

> **Disclaimer** Of course, this is only an analogy and it will break at a lot of different levels and there are a lot of corner cases as with anything Scala; but my point here is that it can be *useful*

At the type level, you can think of `<:` as a the equivalent of `:` at the value level:

```scala
class TypeParamsVsVals {

  type X
  type X1 <: X

  class Buh[T <: X]
  class Oh[T1 <: X1] extends Buh[T1]
  // wait for Scala 3
  // class Oh[T1 <: X1] extends Buh[T = T1]

  type x
  type x1 <: x

  class buh(val t: x)
  class oh(val t1: x1) extends buh(t = t1)
}
```

What I think is the main source of confusion is that at the type level there's no kind distinction between the two sides of `<:`, and to make things worse you can write `T` without any (no pun intended) bound, while you cannot do the same at the value level:

```scala
class NoBounds[T]
// same as 
class AltNoBounds[T <: Any]

// you cannot write
// class noBounds(val t)
class noBounds(val t: Any)
```