# Scala Context Bounds syntax error

Tags: scala

I'm trying to see if I understand Context Bounds in Scala, so I  wrote up a little dummy example to see how the implicit variables get passed around. My code is below.

```
  class Data(_x : Int) {
    var x = _x
  }

  class DataOrdering extends Ordering[Data] {
    def compare(d1 : Data, d2 : Data) : Int = d1.x - d2.x
  }

  def globalCompare[Data : Ordering](d1 : Data, d2 : Data) {
    println("Global compare: " + implicitly[Ordering[Data]].compare(d1, d2))
  }

  def caller()(implicit d : Ordering[Data]) {
    println("Caller")
    globalCompare(new Data(5), new Data(100))
  }

  // Error method here
  def caller2[Data : Ordering]() {
    println("Caller2")
    globalCompare(new Data(50), new Data(100))
  }

  def main() {
    implicit val dataOrdering : DataOrdering = new DataOrdering
    caller
    caller2
  }

  main
```

The caller() method works as I expect in calling globalCompare, but caller2() gives me a compile error

```
  error: class type required but Data found
  globalCompare(new Data(50), new Data(100))
                    ^

  error: class type required but Data found
  globalCompare(new Data(50), new Data(100))
                                  ^
```

I expected caller() and caller2() to be equivalent, but I seem to be missing something. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not `case class Data(x: Int)`? Why the mutable field?

Comment: It was a pretty arbitrary selection, since it wasn't what I cared about in the overall testing.

Comment: Your mind should be geared towards `case class` by default if you don't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In caller2, `Data` is a type parameter, not the class name.

This is probably duped somewhere.

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16489716/1296806), where @TravisBrown calls it [annoying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14023882/334519) in the [extreme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13830404/334519).

I don't know whether it's more annoying when you're shadowing a concrete type name.  I wonder if `Xlint` would have warned you about that. Somebody's linter ought to.

Comment: Thanks! It took a little while, but the explanation makes sense. I do apologize for the duplication as I didn't realize it was a shadow issue (or what that even meant) before reading through the links you provided.