# How can I have a typed (specific) factory in a base trait in Scala?

Tags: scala

Here's the behavior I'm trying to achieve:

```
trait PathLike {
  val given: String

  def factory[T <: PathLike]( g: String ):T

  def +[T <: PathLike]( part: String ): T = factory(this.given+"/"+part)
}

case class Path( given: String ) extends PathLike {
  def factory[Path]( g: String ) = Path(g)
}
case class NonRelativePath( given: String ) extends PathLike {
  def factory[NonRelativePath]( g: String ) = NonRelativePath(g)
}
```

I have other functions in PathLike that use + so simply moving the + function into each of the specific case classes doesn't seem like a good option.

Currently the compiler complains:

```
type mismatch;  found   : com.foo.Path  required: Path  Path.scala
type mismatch;  found   : com.foo.NonRelativePath  required: NonRelativePath    Path.scala
```

Why is it complaining as it has Path/NonRelativePath respectively?  How can I construct a properly typed child of PathLike from within PathLike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `trait` type parameter instead of `method` type parameter since it should be applied on instance creation instead of method application.

```
trait PathLike[T <: PathLike] {
  val given: String

  def factory( g: String ):T

  def +( part: String ): T = factory(this.given+"/"+part)
}

case class Path( given: String ) extends PathLike[Path] {
  def factory( g: String ) = Path(g)
}
case class NonRelativePath( given: String ) extends PathLike[NonRelativePath] {
  def factory( g: String ) = NonRelativePath(g)
}
```

Using `def factory[Path]( g: String ) =` you are creating a new name for methods type parameter. See these answers for additional information about type shadowing: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16489817/406435), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14023882/406435), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13830404/406435).

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly add the return type in the definition.

```
def factory[Path]( g: String ): Path = Path(g)
```